# Visualizing overlapping subproblems in LeetCode Regular Expression question and use of DP

Tags: java, python, string, recursion, dynamic-programming

I just solved [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/regular-expression-matching/description/) problem(10. Regular Expression Matching) on leetcode.com using recursion. I was able to understand the recursive solution. However, when I see the optimized version of this code, it is suggested that I should use **Dynamic Programming**. I'm not able to understand why do we need dynamic programming here ?

- I don't see this problem having overlapping subproblems. Why should we ever use memoization or tabulation ? I am unable to visualize overlapping subproblems.
- Here is where I have reached so far. This is my solution :

  ```
   public static boolean isMatch(String text, String pattern) {

  if (pattern.isEmpty())
      return text.isEmpty();
  boolean first_match = (!text.isEmpty() && (pattern.charAt(0) == text.charAt(0) || pattern.charAt(0) == '.'));

  if (pattern.length() >= 2 && pattern.charAt(1) == '*') {
      return isMatch(text, pattern.substring(2))|| first_match && isMatch(text.substring(1), pattern);
  } else {
      return first_match && isMatch(text.substring(1), pattern.substring(1));
  }
  ```

My understanding of the recursive solution has been that I could see if the next character in the pattern is a *, then there could be 2 scenarios :

1. We skip the current character as well as next character(*) and take the substring of pattern from index 2 and match the remaining substring of the pattern with the current text. This accounts for '0' occurrences for the character preceding *.
2. The * in the pattern will keep absorbing matching characters from the text. As long as we keep getting the same character, they keep matching the star and we keep going ahead.

The other scenario is, if the next character isn't a '*' then we check if the current characters match, if yes then check remaining substrings for both.

I tried dry running this with :

> Input:
>   s = "mississippi"
>   p = "mis*is*p*."
>   Output: false

I can visualize that first 
m and m match,
i and i match
(linear recursion so far).
Now begins the complex part because s and s match but s's next character is a star. If I call, matching '0' occurrences as scenario 1 and absorbing matching characters in the * as scenario 2 then the recursive calls would look like this :

> Scenario 1 :  text is ssissippi and remaining pattern is is*p*.
>
> s and i characters didn't match
>
> Scenario 2 : remaining text is sissippi and  pattern is s*is*p*.
>
> Scenario 1 :  text is sissippi and remaining pattern is is*p*.
>
> s and i characters didn't match
>
> Scenario 2 : remaining text is issippi and  pattern is s*is*p*.
>
> Scenario 1 :  text is issippi and remaining pattern is is*p*.
>
> characters matched so next recursive call with text : ssippi and
>   pattern as : s*p*.
>
> Scenario 1 :  text is ssippi and remaining pattern is p*.
>
> Scenario 1 :  text is ssippi and remaining pattern is .
>
> characters matched so next recursive call with text : sippi and
>   pattern as :
>
> Scenario 2 : remaining text is sippi and  pattern is p*.
>
> Scenario 2 : remaining text is sippi and  pattern is s*p*.
>
> Scenario 1 :  text is sippi and remaining pattern is p*.
>
> Scenario 1 :  text is sippi and remaining pattern is .
>
> characters matched so next recursive call with text : ippi and pattern
>   as :   Scenario 2 : remaining text is ippi and  pattern is p*.
>
> Scenario 2 : remaining text is ippi and  pattern is s*p*.
>
> Scenario 1 :  text is ippi and remaining pattern is p*.
>
> Scenario 1 :  text is ippi and remaining pattern is .
>
> characters matched so next recursive call with text : ppi and pattern
>   as :
>
> Scenario 2 : remaining text is ppi and  pattern is p*.
>
> Scenario 2 : remaining text is ppi and  pattern is s*p*.
>
> Scenario 2 : remaining text is ssippi and  pattern is s*is*p*.

And finally return False.

No where in this solution can I figure out if there are any overlapping subproblems or any solution that we could ever re-use ?

I even tried looking up on youtube. [This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3hda49XcDE&t=209s) does not tell how we reach this solution, he just simply dry runs the solution because he knows its a DP problem.

How do we figure out if this is a DP problem ? What is the intuition behind reaching a DP solution for this problem ?

I've looked up a lot on the internet and still I'm not able to figure out where are the overlapping subproblems and how do we conclude if its a DP problem. I tried making a recursion tree also for this one but still couldn't figure out where we could re-use the previously calculated solutions.

Can anyone help me visualize the overlapping sub-problems and also help me conclude how do you figure out if it's a DP problem and reach a bottom up solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a test case, text = `"hhT"`, pattern = `".*h.*P"`.

Try printing both text and pattern at the very first line of your `isMatch` function call. You'll see text `"T"` and pattern `".*P"` appear twice. So yes, this problem does have overlapping subproblems.

Part of the reason I struggled to come up with an example is your code is pretty elegant. My comparatively badly written code had a lot more overlaps.

It happens because, `"hh"` of text can be consumed two ways. The `"h"` of pattern can be matched to both first and second `"h"` of text. But either way, matching `"hh"` would take up `".*h"` from pattern, and you are left with `"T"` and `".*P"`.

So unlike Fibonacci or other classical DP problems, subproblem overlap here isn't guaranteed to happen. But it can happen, specially when you have lots of special characters.

Comment: Would really appreciate if we can have a more clear case of overlapping subproblem, This example is still hard to find for overlapping problems